# How can you retrieve send data from a Triggered SMS send based off the customer key?

Tags: marketing-cloud

We want to pull down all the mobile numbers that have been completed for a triggered SMS send. I checked out the _Sent table and there are two fields that look like they would work to query off of, but I haven't had any luck with them (TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID & TriggeredSendCustomerKey). Any idea how I can access this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to query on _SmsLog

The columns there are: SmsJobId, MobileNumber, Details, CreatedDate, Category, Name.